# Prove that 5nˆ2 + 2n - 1 is O(nˆ2) for n >= 1

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Exercise: *Prove that* **5nˆ2 + 2n - 1** *is* **O(nˆ2)** for n >= 1

This is what I did:

> 1. 5nˆ2 + 2n - 1 < 5nˆ2 + 2n.
> 2. 5nˆ2 - 1 < 5nˆ2

this means that C= 5 and n0 = 1

I'm a bit nervous because I feel this was too simple of a procedure. Did I do something wrong or is this alright?

Thanks!

Comment: You are correct to be nervous.  There is a logical disconnect between the 1st and 2nd steps.  You have somehow "lost" the `2n` term.  Try again.

Comment: @StephenC I subtracted it from both sides, was I wrong to do so?

Comment: Yea. Subtracting a term on both sides of an inequality is mathematically sound ... but it doesn't help you prove what you need to prove. What you need to establish is `5n^2 + 2n -1 < C n^2` where `n > n0` for some `C` and some `n0`. Your transformations don't prove that.

Comment: Your approach should be to prove a chain like this:  `5nˆ2 + 2n - 1` is less or equal to `f1(n)`, and `f1(n)` is less or equal to `f2(n)`, and ... `fj(n)` is less or equal to `Cn^2`.  For some C and all `n >= n0`.

Comment: Questions about theoretical computer science are a better fit for [cs.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, big O notation regards **asymptotic** growth, so the `n >= 1` is actually redundant.
By the definition  of big O, `f(n) = O(g(n))` if there exists some `c, n0 > 0` s.t. for all `n > n0` it holds that `f(n) <= cg(n)`.
So in our case: `5n^2 + 2n - 1 <= 5n^2 + 2n <= 5n^2 + 2n^2 = 7n^2` as for every natural integer it holds that `n^2 >= n`.
Choose `c = 7, n0 = 1` and for all `n > n0` we get that `5n^2 + 2n -1 <= 7n^2 = cn^2`.
Conculsion: `5n^2 + 2n - 1 = O(n^2)`.